# How to program batch file to copy from source to destination

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I need to program a batch file to copy from source to destination. Once user enters source and destination paths, the batch file will copy files from source to destination. So far i have

```
set /p source=\PATH\TO\SOURCE
xcopy %source% "c:\PATH\TO\DESTINATION" /e /h /k /o
```

But this only allows for user to enter input for source paths. I need the code that allows user to enter destination paths as well. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
SET /P USERSOURCE=Please enter the source path: 
SET /P USERDEST=Please enter the destination path:
xcopy %USERSOURCE% %USERDEST% /e /h /k /o
```

That should do what you want (as long as the parameters you listed are correct).

Comment: Please remember this is not instant messaging. Sometimes you get a reply, sometimes you don't. Begging for one is just noise, and will end up getting things flagged for moderator review.